# Can't figure out how to place anything beside a floated div

Tags: html, css

I have a floated `div` that has a `200px` margin from the right side, and I want to place a `table` on that empty space.

This is the CSS for the `div`:

```
#testo {
  border-right: solid black 1px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 200px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 7px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

But the `table` goes under it? Why?

Comment: @Aaron Floats don't take up 100% of the width https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/9zkygtwd/

Comment: @JuanMendes it depends on the amount of content inside the element.

Comment: @Aaron That's why your statement is incorrect, it takes the width of its content, it may be 100% of the width if it's got a lot of content. The real problem is that the margin takes up space, so the table gets pushed down

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the margin of your floating element still takes up space. Therefore, another element in the flow cannot be in that space and gets pushed to the next line.

One solution is to absolutely position the table on the right so that it's removed from the flow.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper div {
  margin-right: 200px;
  float: left;
}
table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 0;
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Uno Dos Tres Quatro Cinco no Dos Tres Quatro Cinco no Dos Tres Quatro Cinco. Iti ni san shi, Iti ni san shi. Un deux trois quatre. Un deux trois quatre. Um dois três quatro. Um dois três quatro. Uno Dos Tres Quatro Cinco no Dos Tres Quatro Cinco no
    Dos Tres Quatro Cinco. Iti ni san shi, Iti ni san shi. Un deux trois quatre. Un deux trois quatre. Um dois três quatro. Um dois três quatro</div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your div has an 100% width.
Set a **width/max-width** to this `div` and the table won't go under.

Answer (score -1):

It is happening because the div has a `display: block` by default.

Regardless its size, it will take the full line on the page.

Try to set `display:inline-block` to the div and see if it works.

Comment: its still under it, the only way to get it to work is to set a width for the div but that would also mess up my margin

Comment: When you float something, it doesn't display as a block anymore.